# Using libpng for Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, libpng

I can't compile an open-source project that uses libpng under Ubuntu using gcc.

I've installed with apt-get libpng3 and libpng12-dev, but autoconf says that 'libpng' isn't installed yet.

How to make clear for autoconf that libpng3 is libpng?

Comment: libpng3 is *not* libpng. Only dev packages are meaningful. There is no dev package for libpng3 because it's an obsolete compatibility library. Use only libpng12.

Comment: Yes, I can do it. But how to explain to autoconf that my libpng12 is the libpng he is looking for?

Comment: You may have to modify your project if it demands a specific obsolete library. It is hard to say more without seeing relevant error messages and logs.

Comment: it depends on libpng, not libpng3

Comment: If you want us to read the `README` file for you, you have to tell us which project's `README`.

Comment: the problem is not in project, the problem is with libpng. autoconf thinks that it isn't installed, but it is. The thing is to explain.

Comment: Try `./configure --help` to figure if there's an option to specify libpng.